# How wide/long is the Quinjet from the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, vehicles

I've been working on my own worldbuilding project for the last 2 years, and I've recently started working on vehicles. I'm designing a ship similar to a Quinjet, but designed for further travel so it comes with a 1 person bathroom for changing dirty gear/doing your do.

Does anyone know the dimensions of a Quinjet in the MCU? Since this is my "base craft" for lack of a better word, I'm going to use those measurements to make sure the changing room will fit. My current changing room design is 16 feet squared, holds 1 person, comes with a sink, toilet, and bench for changing gear (like you'd see in a pool changing room, just a wooden/plastic bench). I found a size chart from a while ago on Reddit, and it lists the Quinjet as being 16.5 meters/54.1 feet long, which is certainly long enough, but now I'm unsure of the width it'd have to be.

The specifications for the ship as a whole are simple, only needing to hold a maximum of 8 occupants, 2 pilots, and 6 passengers, and house the toilet/changing room. Storage for gear fits under the seats like the overhead of an airplane, so that's not a problem. It's not meant to carry any other vehicles, just people.

[Size chart I used](https://www.reddit.com/r/shield/comments/i99xbp/mcu_ship_size_comparison_with_almost_all_agents/)

Comment: You are not trying to *actually* build this plane, correct? On the other hand, if it is worldbuilding, do the exact dimensions really matter that much? Surely an approximate size  gauged by watching the show would work.

Comment: I may make a 3D model in Blender at some point, but no, no real building it in real life if that's what you mean. I'm still in high school, nowhere near skilled enough to build my own high tech military vessel lol. I do not know how to make an approximate size based off the show sadly, or I would try that.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! If you're interesting in world-building, you'll probably want to check out [Worldbuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/), although this specific question (the dimensions of the Quinjet) belongs here and not there.

Comment: I would start by finding a shot showing a person of known height standing against the side of the jet with a head-on camera angle, and then employ a little trigonometry.

Comment: I do not know trigonometry sadly, but I will try googling it! Thank you! :D

Comment: I really don’t think there’s gonna be any canon on this. The best you’ll be able to do is approximate it. [This Reddit post gives it a good go](https://www.reddit.com/r/shield/comments/7d9zpo/what_is_the_exact_size_of_the_quinjet/dpwklcw/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf&context=3).

Comment: BTW, 16 feet square is not the same thing as 16 square feet. The former is the size of a master bedroom, and rather large for a changing room.

Comment: Oh. I meant 16 square feet srry. 4x4 feet lol. Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is Captain America by the quinjet in *The Winter Soldier*:

[image]

Yes, Cap is a bit closer to the camera than the quinjet is, but we can still approximate.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America%27s_shield#Circular_shield) Captain's shield is about 2.5 feet (0.76 meters)

[image]

It takes approximately 10 shields for the length of the jet, which would be around 25 feet or 7.6 meters. you can add a bit more length because of the perspective of Cap and the jet, so say around 30 feet (~9 meters).

From the picture below, the quinjet seems to have pretty square dimensions, so the dimensions seem to be the same for the length of the ship.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! :o This is perfect!

Answer (score 3):

> Ultimate Quinjet measures over 4” (12cm) high, 15” (40cm) long and 11” (28cm) wide.

https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/avengers-ultimate-quinjet-76126

Here's a discussion of scale factors:
https://brickarchitect.com/scale/

Using the 1:25 horizontal scale, the Quinjet is 3m high, 10m long, and 7m wide.

Here's a [site](https://aminoapps.com/c/warfare-roleplay/page/item/quinjet/jdrg_XPuoIgMzYDv28gKp5Rq2KQg6MBjdev) that gives the dimensions as 4m high, 9m long, 10m wide.

A [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/shield/comments/7d9zpo/what_is_the_exact_size_of_the_quinjet/) thread gives 4.8, 12.3, 11.1.

Another reddit [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/shield/comments/hhoz33/aircraft_of_shield_size_chart/) gives the dimension 16.5m with no source.

Apparently, there's going to be an actual Quinjet [prop](https://www.disneyfoodblog.com/2020/08/19/photos-check-out-the-recently-installed-quinjet-at-avengers-campus-in-disneyland/) at Disneyland. From the photos, it looks like it's quite a bit more than 4m high if you include the vertical fins.

Comment: That aminoapps link returns a 404 for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a lot of scaling, and am actually responsible for the size chart which lists the Quinjet as 16.5 meters long. After comparing the Quinjet to such things as an Aircraft Carrier runway, people standing near it. I've found the Quinjet to be ~18 meters long, give or take a meter. Additionally, [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/shield/comments/7d9zpo/what_is_the_exact_size_of_the_quinjet/) which lists the Quinjet's length as 12.3 meters made the assumption that "The Bus" is the same length as a real C-17 Globemaster III or 53 meters. The Bus is in fact 76 meters long as seen in [this layout](https://nerdbasego.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/busblueprint30-1.jpg), which would make the Quinjet ~17.6 meters long.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It's nice to know the source of the 16.5m figure, but this would be a much better answer if you included your size comparisons, much as the first answer does.  The more details the better!